# Angular drag and drop - nested lists

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create drag and drop dashboard, and I came upon a great nested list on: http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested

This is done with AngularJs javascript framework. Since I am not experienced with it, can anyone please point me in the right direction.

As you can see, the demo version has Dropzone A, and Dropzone B, and those zones are not draggable. What I want to do is make this Dropzone draggable between themselves, so it can be reordered. So the Dropzone B comes first and vice versa. Did someone try this already?

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular-ui-tree to implement this, [link](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree), [examples](http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example)

Comment: Thank you Jim, this is something that I need